# If a continuous function is never $0$, it must either be always positive or always negative

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $I$ be an interval, and let $f : I \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function on $I$. Suppose $f$ is never $0$ on $I$. Prove that $f$ must either be always positive or always negative.

---

I was thinking of proving this with cases: case 1 assuming $f$ is always positive, case 2 assuming $f$ is always negative, and case 3 assuming $f$ can be positive and negative. I would disprove case 3, and that leaves case 1 and 2 to be the only feasible solutions?

Comment: I was thinking of proving this with cases:
case 1 assuming f is always positive, case 2 assuming f is always negative, and case 3 assuming f can be positive and negative.

I would disprove case 3, and that leaves case 1 and 2 to be the only feasible solutions?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem

Comment: I was planning on using the IVT to disprove case 3. However, case 1 and case 2 are intuitively true, which seems too simple to me.

Comment: If the Intermediate Value Theorem has already been proved, you are finished. If not, suppose WLG the function is negative at $a$ and positive at $b$. Let $c$ be the sup of all $x\lt b$ at which $f(x)\lt 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The most on-target way to prove this statement would be to prove its contrapositive: "Suppose that $f$ is neither always positive nor always negative. Then $f$ is somewhere $0$ on $I$." This is provable from the IVT in about two lines.

Moral: an implication and its contrapositive are always equivalent, and often one is much more straightforward to prove than the other.